# Keep movement until a key is pressed (Duplicate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[THIS ANSWER IS A DUPLICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182846/pressing-a-button-to-have-constant-movement/49183561#49183561)

### I am remaking snake as a challenge but I cannot get the snake to move in one direction continuously.

I re-did the movement to work better, this is what i have now:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
RED = (240, 0, 0)
x = y = 0
sizex = sizey = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sizex,sizey))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:  # 
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    x -= 25
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    x += 25
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                    y -= 25
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    y += 25

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, pygame.Rect(x,y,tilesize,tilesize))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)
```

Currently,

```
elif event.key == K_DOWN:
        y += 25
```

doesn't move the rectangle along the screen continuously.

I'd like a solution that carries on moving it until a key is pressed.

Comment: plez include more explanations in your post, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182846/pressing-a-button-to-have-constant-movement/49183561#49183561

Comment: Do you mean `for x, y in screen:` ?

Comment: Do you get a ``TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not iterable``? If yes, please include it in the question. If not, please elaborate on "not working" -- crashes with an error, just does't move, moves in the wrong direction...

Comment: OK, asking because the copied code (excluding the image) gives me that error. Can you try running it removing ``tile`` and see what happens?

Comment: the code is _quite_ different...

Comment: pls forget about it not doing anything i just want that to be in a loop until you press another key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the movement carry on until another key is pressed down (using something similar to what you did), you can use a `velocity` variable storing your current velocity in the directions (depending on your personal preferences, it can be a list, a tuple, two variables or your own `class Velocity`).

When a key is pressed, you set the respective velocity to the "moving" valueand all other ones to zero.

```
# x and y are the respective positions when drawing; we are currently inside the event-handling loop
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    vel_x = vel_y = 0  # if you only want this to happen for arrow keys, do it here
    if event.key == K_UP:
        vel_y = -5
    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
        vel_y = 5
    ...
```

after the loop, before drawing:

```
x += vel_x
y += vel_y
# you might want to check we're not outside the screen here
```

A few extra notes:

- <del>try</del> make sure to have ***one* event loop**. If your event-handling code is too long, put in into a separate function.
- the speed issue you talked about *could* be caused by drawing lots of little images on the screen, you might want to verify this
- do you handle cases when the player tries exiting the screen?

Comment: Im not sure thats what u want to do, i want it so if if i press a key (not hold it down) it continues to move in that direction until another key is pressed.

Comment: @Glitchd sorry, it should be right now. I misunderstood what you wanted

Comment: So with this code put into mine properly i can press the down/up/left/right arrow key once and it will continue to move in that direction?

Comment: @Glitchd until another key is pressed, it should

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it tomorrow as it is very late where i am

Comment: @Glitchd if it still doesn't work, just write another comment -- I'll look into it

Comment: Ok thank you and sorry i kept changing the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188967/discussion-between-user24343-and-glitchd).